# Error while creating customer in Stripe Subscription

Tags: java, grails, gson, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am trying to integrate stripe in grails 2.2.1. Stripe-java-5.4.0 and gson-2.2.4-sources.jar. I have used js script in the view. But I am getting com.stripe.net.APIResource error.

Imports are

```
import com.stripe.model.Subscription
import com.stripe.net.APIResource
import com.stripe.Stripe
import com.google.gson.*
```

last 3 imports are not used.

**View**

```
<g:form controller="home" action="stripePayment" class="register-form" role="form">
        <script
                src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                data-key="pk_test_xxx"
                data-amount="2000"
                data-name="Demo Site"
                data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
                data-image="../images/logo.png">
        </script>
    </g:form>
```

**Controller**

```
def stripePayment(){
        String token = params.stripeToken;

        Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_xxx"; test

        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("email", "test@test.test");

        Customer customer = Customer.create(params);

    }
```

**Error**

```
  stripeToken: tok_1AXWxW2eZvKYlo2CKovnV4Hl
stripeTokenType: card
stripeEmail: test@test.test
com.stripe.net.APIResource. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Executing action [stripePayment] of controller [safety4truckers.HomeController]  caused exception: Runtime error executing action
    Line | Method
->>  195 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by ControllerExecutionException: Runtime error executing action
->>  195 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by InvocationTargetException: null
->>  195 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by NoClassDefFoundError: com.stripe.net.APIResource
->>  274 | forName   in java.lang.Class
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     30 | stripePayment in safety4truckers.HomeController$$EQNI4WN9
|    195 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: Do you have these dependencies in your BuildConfig? It seems like they have not been added correctly.

Comment: I have saved jar files in lib directory. Import is working. Now I am getting this error:
com.google.gson.GsonBuilder. Stacktrace follows:
Message: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
Is this because gson is correct import is not done?